# Operate on collection once, to sum weighted average of fees

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
return new SchoolFees(
        new Percentage(schoolFeesResult.Sum(x => (x.Amount.Value / totalFees) * x.TuitionFee.Value)),
        new Percentage(schoolFeesResult.Sum(x => (x.Amount.Value / totalFees) * x.TravellingFee.Value)),
        new Percentage(schoolFeesResult.Sum(x => (x.Amount.Value / totalFees) * x.ResidentialFee.Value)));
```

Is there a way I can operate on `schoolFeesResult` once to calculate the weighted average of each of the different types of fees (`Tuition`, `Travelling`, `Residence`). Basically I don't want `(x.Amount.Value / totalFees)` to appear 3 times in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another brain-breaking solution

```
Func<Func<Fee, decimal>, decimal> totalFee = feeSelector =>
   schoolFeesResult.Sum(x => x.Amount.Value / totalFees * feeSelector(x));

return new SchoolFees(
   new Percentage(totalFee(f => f.TuitionFee.Value)),
   new Percentage(totalFee(f => f.TravellingFee.Value)),
   new Percentage(totalFee(f => f.ResidentialFee.Value))
);
```

Or even shorter:

```
Func<Func<Fee, decimal>, Percentage> percentageOf = feeSelector =>
   new Percentage(schoolFeesResult.Sum(x => 
         x.Amount.Value / totalFees * feeSelector(x)));

return new SchoolFees(
   percentageOf(f => f.TuitionFee.Value),
   percentageOf(f => f.TravellingFee.Value),
   percentageOf(f => f.ResidentialFee.Value)
);
```

Comment: +1: Nice, I like it. Note: This will also enumerate `schoolFeesResult` three times.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth thanks! yes, it enumerates three times, but it Nice :) BTW there is little difference - it enumerates three times (as original code does) but i don't calculate each `weight * fee` :)

Comment: It will calculate each weight (`x.Amount.Value / totalFees`) three times, just like the original code. And just like the original code, it will calculate each indivitual `weight * fee` only once. So, in terms of computation it does the same. Just with more style :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this:

```
var fees = from fee in schoolFeesResult
           let weight = fee.Amount.Value / totalFees
           select new 
           {
               TuitionFee = weight * fee.TuitionFee.Value,
               TravellingFee = weight * fee.TravellingFee.Value,
               ResidentialFee = weight * fee.ResidentialFee.Value
           };

// if the calculation of the fees is a performance bottleneck,
// uncomment the next line:
// fees = fees.ToList();

return new SchoolFees(
    new Percentage(fees.Sum(x => x.TuitionFee),
    new Percentage(fees.Sum(x => x.TravellingFee),
    new Percentage(fees.Sum(x => x.ResidentialFee));
```

You could go even further:

```
var fees = (from fee in schoolFeesResult
            let weight = fee.Amount.Value / totalFees
            group fee by 1 into g
            select new 
            {
                TuitionFee = g.Sum(x => weight * x.TuitionFee.Value),
                TravellingFee = g.Sum(x => weight * x.TravellingFee.Value),
                ResidentialFee = g.Sum(x => weight * x.ResidentialFee.Value)
            }).Single();

return new SchoolFees(
    new Percentage(fees.TuitionFee,
    new Percentage(fees.TravellingFee,
    new Percentage(fees.ResidentialFee);
```

But I doubt that this second version is a good idea. It makes the code hard to understand. I added it purely for academic reasons, to show what is possible.

Comment: I think you need `ToList` or each fee will be calculated three times

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: That's correct. If that's a problem, you can add `ToList` without a problem. I didn't add it, because I don't think makes a real difference here. And it would have made the code look less "nice" :-) Nevertheless, I added an comment, because it indeed is an important point.

Comment: Ha-ha :) +1 for nice code. Who cares about performance, if code looks nice!

Answer (score 1):

I use this implementation of `WeightedAverage` as an extension method to `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static double? WeightedAverage<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source
                                                       , Func<TSource, float> weightField
                                                       , Func<TSource, double> propertyToWeight)
{
    var total = source.Sum(weightField);

    var sum = source.Select(item => weightField(item) * propertyToWeight(item)).Sum();
    return sum / total;

}
```

There are a few overloads to deal with `single`, `single?` and `double` of course. Perhaps you could adjust this to fit in with what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you could put it in another query, imho it's also more redable then:

```
var percentages = schoolFeesResult
    .Select(x => new { SFR = x, AmoundDivFees = (x.Amount.Value / totalFees)})
    .Select(x => new { 
        TuitionFee = x.AmoundDivFees * x.SFR.TuitionFee.Value,
        TravellingFee = x.AmoundDivFees * x.SFR.TravellingFee.Value,
        ResidentialFee = x.AmoundDivFees * x.SFR.ResidentialFee.Value
    });
return new SchoolFees(
    new Percentage(percentages.Sum(x => x.TuitionFee)),
    new Percentage(percentages.Sum(x => x.TravellingFee)),
    new Percentage(percentages.Sum(x => x.ResidentialFee)));
```

Of course i could not test it.